# This method call passes a null value for a nonnull method parameter. Either the parameter is annotated as a parameter that should always be nonnull

Tags: java, sonarqube

SonarQube error for below method, any suggestion experts on how to resolve the issue -This method call passes a null value for a nonnull method parameter. Either the parameter is annotated as a parameter that should always be nonnull, or analysis has shown that it will always be dereferenced.

```
    public ByteArrayResource readFile() throws IOException {
        byte[] content = null;

        try (S3Object object = amazonS3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key))) {
            content = IOUtils.toByteArray(object.getObjectContent());
            return new ByteArrayResource(content);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("IOException caught while reading file", e);
        } 
        return new ByteArrayResource(content);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with `return new ByteArrayResource(content);` statement outside of `try/catch` block. As your method is throwing `IOException`, you shouldn't be catching it. Below should resolve it:

```
public ByteArrayResource readFile() throws IOException {
    try (S3Object object = amazonS3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key))) {
        byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(object.getObjectContent());
        return new ByteArrayResource(content);
    }
}
```